# Ubuntu to Debian, pulseaudio works differently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, audio, pulse-audio

Simple case: one application and one output device. I'm also using pavucontrol.

In Ubuntu, I could change the volume of the application or the output device without affecting the other's volume. However in Debian:

1. When I change the device volume, the application volume scales accordingly
2. When I change the application volume to a value greater than the current device volume, the device volume goes up too

What configuration am I missing to make it work in the old way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `flat-volumes=no` in PulseAudio's daemon.conf configuration file.